# How to combine TRIM and LOWER functions in JPQL?

Tags: jpql

I need to perform the following select:

```
select c.address from Customer c where lower(trim(c.name)) = :name
```

But I get the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

Any idea how can I combine `trim` with `lower`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I discovered the solution, you must use `both` in order for the statment to work:

```
select c.address from Customer c where lower(trim(both from c.name)) = :name
```

Comment: What does that mean here? both?

Comment: `both from` is an optional SQL clause in the `trim` statement, it cannot affect the query. Indeed my query works without it.